# Compare two arrays of strings - KQL

Tags: kql

We are trying to compare two arrays of strings and matching keywords/domains from the first array (url1) with url2. Can we use a wild card or alternate way to match keywords/domains in url1 with the whole strings in url2?

Sample Query:
`let url1 = dynamic(["test2.com","test4.com"]); let url2 = dynamic( ["test.com", "test2.com/1234/", "test3.com"]); print result = set_difference(url2,url1)`

Current Results:
`["test.com","test2.com/1234/","test3.com"]`

Expected Results:
`["test.com","test3.com"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let url1 = dynamic(["test2.com","test4.com"]);
let url2 = dynamic( ["test.com", "test2.com/1234/", "test3.com"]); 
let url2_clean = toscalar(print url = url2 | mv-apply url to typeof(string) on (summarize make_list(trim_end("/.*", url))));
print result = set_difference(url2_clean, url1)
```

| result |
| --- |
| ["test.com","test3.com"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA01P2wrCMAx9F/yHsKdOdGOXN/FLREbpMin2RpsJEz/e0DFmnsLJucUgwRxNAzcYFyetVuJeECZqK%20Vtcc57n/dHeT0ezMpv//iwClY%207OK6abu%203qBu84DdZFAGpWMr8klJI6MIUbt8YzDHfMG%20LzIEs2SUPNAS0E8iEVOfJXgHIs3Wyqg/CFa%20cDA6keCzHdCNoqirE5dgdcnDL6wZEdNsiGMS0jDqacKITqHYe2VNU/4AopUj2yIBAAA=)

In case you need it on a row-level:

```
print url1 = dynamic(["test2.com","test4.com"]), url2 = dynamic( ["test.com", "test2.com/1234/", "test3.com"])
| mv-apply url2 to typeof(string) on (summarize url2_clean = make_list(trim_end("/.*", url2)))
| project result = set_difference(url2_clean, url1)
```

| result |
| --- |
| ["test.com","test3.com"] |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA02OywrCMBBF937F0FUitaWPrV8iEkI6lWheJFOh4sfbNkrdXYZz7twQtSOYomngDMPspNWKXQrCRG2lvC3KLfdbvvJyRds/FDKbUdi9umm7vv6duq9%20eIN9nmQIZs5F5IHmgH5kiZYlNw7eAUuTtTLqF26QUAalW35a%20UBhdCK2sFagG1hRV8cij%20J8rQ/R31ERREyToUVKSGLQ44gRnUK2F25Wwz/NT5QiAQEAAA==)